# Qgis node tool not working

Tags: nodetool

due to unknown reasons my node tool stopped working appropriately. More precisely, I can select nodes just by selection window, not each node individually. Also, I can't move the nodes.

I attached a print screen with the snapping settings, in case the problem might be there.

[image]

Comment: Try to reinstall QGIS.

Comment: Done this multiple times. Also installed different versions 2.14 or 2.18.